# Баг со словарем в Python 3

Tags: python

Заметил баг при работе со словарём начиная с версии Python 3.6 до 3.9.9, а именно если использовать создание словаря со списком внутри с помощью **dict.fromkeys(arr, [])** , то при добавлении значений к определенному ключу, они добавляются ко всем ключам в словаре.
Подробнее на примерах ниже:

```
arr = [i for i in range(1, 6)]
my_dict = {1: [], 2: [], 3: [], 4: [], 5: []}

for _ in range(1, 3):
    my_dict[1] += [50]

print(my_dict)      # {1: [50, 50], 2: [], 3: [], 4: [], 5: []}
```

Как и ожидалось, код отработал корректно, дважды добавив к ключу "1" значение "50".
В следующем примере, создаем словарь с использованием **dict.fromkeys(arr, [])**  :

```
arr = [i for i in range(1, 6)]
my_dict = dict.fromkeys(arr, [])

for _ in range(1, 3):
    my_dict[1] += [50]

print(my_dict)      # {1: [50, 50], 2: [50, 50], 3: [50, 50], 4: [50, 50], 5: [50, 50]}
```

Код отработал непредсказуемым образом, дважды добавив значение "50" ко всем ключам в словаре. Кто может объяснить почему так происходит?

Comment: Это не баг, а "фича". По аналогии с инициализацией списка. `a = [[]]*10;
a[0].append(2)
` - тоже добавится ко всем подспискам. Но со списками вроде все быстро выучивают, что правильно создание списка списков, как вариант, нужно делать через цикл `a = [[] for _ in range(10)]`.

Comment: Так что по аналогии со списками делайте через цикл - `my_dict = {x:[] for x in arr}
`

Comment: Это не баг, вы создали один-единственный список и запихнули его во все ключи. А так как список один, то и значения всех ключей обновляются все сразу

Comment: Благодарю за пояснения!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Рассмотрим на примере.
Вы думаете, что инициализация словаря пройдёт по этому сценарию:

```
my_dict = {}
for x in range(1, 6):
    my_dict[x] = []

print(my_dict)  #  {1: [], 2: [], 3: [], 4: [], 5: []}

my_dict[1].append("A")
print(my_dict)  #  {1: ['A'], 2: [], 3: [], 4: [], 5: []}
```

И вроде всё должно работать как надо.

Но нет. Когда вы определяете словарь вот так `dict.fromkeys(arr, [])`, то список, по сути, создаётся всего раз и ссылка на него идёт во все элементы словаря. Т.е. поведение эквивалентно данному коду:

```
my_dict = {}
my_list = []
for x in range(1, 6):
    my_dict[x] = my_list

print(my_dict)  #  {1: [], 2: [], 3: [], 4: [], 5: []}

my_dict[1].append("A")
print(my_dict)  # {1: ['A'], 2: ['A'], 3: ['A'], 4: ['A'], 5: ['A']}
```

Казалось бы, нюанс всего лишь в том, что пустой список задаётся через промежуточную переменную... Но зато какая разница в результате!

---

Поэтому правильным будет создавать каждый элемент со своим пустым списком. Например, через цикл.

```
my_dict = {x:[] for x in arr}
```

Answer (score 0):

В дополнение к уже сказанному. Легко ведь проверить, одинаковые элементы-списки лежат в словаре или разные:

```
...
print(*map(id, my_dict.values()))
```

Вывод в первом примере:

```
{1: [50, 50], 2: [], 3: [], 4: [], 5: []}
140422771453616 140422771564048 140422771557632 140422771606224 140422833252864
```

Вывод во втором примере:

```
{1: [50, 50], 2: [50, 50], 3: [50, 50], 4: [50, 50], 5: [50, 50]}
140422771613856 140422771613856 140422771613856 140422771613856 140422771613856
```

Видно, что в первом случае `id` списков разные, а во втором у всех один `id`, т.е. это просто один и тот же список.

Comment: Можно проверить даже сразу после создания `my_dict` (ещё до добавления новых значений). И также увидеть, что во втором случае `id` у всех элементов будет един.